# Json array is PHP + HTML (table)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I use the API from one of the tools I have access to.

My query is as follows:

```html
<?php

$url = 'url';
$data = array("domains" => array("domains.com","domains2.com"));

$postdata = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
?>
```

The answer received is:

```
{"params":{"domains":["domains.com","domains2.com"]},"results":{"domains.com":{"keywords":1387,"keywords_top":208,"traffic":1818,"traffic_potential":62821,"search_volume":201090,"search_volume_top":15830},"domains2.com":{"keywords":1513,"keywords_top":222,"traffic":3609,"traffic_potential":42671,"search_volume":136590,"search_volume_top":24850}}}
```

Is it possible to present the results in the table?

I have no idea how to do it. Loop foreach?

```
$datas = json_decode($result,true);

    echo '<table>';
    foreach($datas as $resulte){

        foreach($resulte as $wynik){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$wynik['keywords'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$wynik['keywords_top'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$wynik['traffic'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$wynik['traffic_potential'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$wynik['search_volume'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$wynik['search_volume_top'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to loop over them and foreach? Possibly after [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)-ing them? Or what else have you tried?

Comment: Yes, loop. Why not try?

Comment: I tried however nei comes out.

echo $ result;
$ datas = json_decode ($ result, true);

echo '<table>';
        foreach ($ datas as $ resulte) {
        foreach ($ resulte as $ result) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'. $ result-> keywords. '</ td>';
echo '<td>'. $ result -> phone. '</ td>';
echo '<td>'. $ result -> email. '</ td>';
echo '</ tr>';
       }
        }
        echo '</ table>';

Comment: Can you update your question and add the code above?

Comment: Reading your comment, you are decode the json into array while access the value like object, please remove the `true` parameter from `json_decode`,  or you can access the value using index: `$result['keywords']`, `$result['phone']`, etc

Comment: @catcon I've edited my code.

Comment: The errors are quite self-explanatory: your JSON does not have "keywords" anywhere, nor the properties mentioned in the other error messages.

Comment: Combines with this since yesterday, can I ask for little help?

Comment: Your domain information only have score1, score2,..,score6 indexes, where do you get those indexes you want the values from.

Comment: @catcon - look my code, I've edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the index the wrong way, the data you want is in `$datas['results']`, you just need to loop through `$datas['result']`:

```
   $datas = json_decode($result,true);
   echo '<table>';
   foreach($datas['results'] as $domainName => $domain){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$domainName.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$domain['keywords'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$domain['keywords_top'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$domain['traffic'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$domain['traffic_potential'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$domain['search_volume'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$domain['search_volume_top'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
   }
   echo '</table>';
```

[Snippets](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2335026c23913ab6a855f8ccf3134117975c061)

Comment: Thanks! And I wanted to write out the domain name again ?

domain name 1387 208 1818 62821 201090 15830

Comment: Each domain's information is indexed by its domain name, I updated my answer with `$domainName`